# Chamar funções/procedimento através de botões utilizando PHP Orientado a Objeto

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, orientação-a-objetos, button

Estou iniciando no PHP O.O e estou com dificuldade em chamar as funções que estão na classe através de botões HTML.

Na verdade, não é em chamar e sim em setar os valores que estão na função.
Exemplo:

```
<?php

Class Conta{

  public $saldo;

  public function __construct(){

    $this->saldo = 50;
  }
  public function getSaldo(){

    return $this->saldo;
  }
  public function setAdd(){

    $this->saldo = $this->saldo - 10;
  }
}
$c = new Conta();
$c->getSaldo();
$c->setAdd();
$c->getSaldo();

?>
```

Fazendo dessa forma, o programa funciona exatamente como eu quero, mostra o saldo inicial, depois altera o saldo e mostra o valor atual. Toda vez que eu invoco o método getAdd() ele altera o valor do Saldo.

Porém, eu gostaria de fazer isso por uma interface em HTML, por exemplo utilizando botões:

```
<button onclick="saldo()">Saldo</button>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Criei duas funções, uma chamando o arquivo saldo.php e a outra chamando add.php com auxílio do AJAX:

```
function saldo(){

    var xhttp
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "saldo.php?", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function add(){

    var xhttp
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "add.php?", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Nos arquivos saldo.php e add.php eu apenas estou invocando o método.
Ex.:

```
<?php

  require_once "class.php";

  $c->getSaldo();
?>
```

Como a tentativa por AJAX havia falhado, tentei também forçando a conversa entre JavaScript e PHP, tipo assim:

```
function saldo(){

        s = "<?php {$c->getSaldo();} ?>";
        document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML = s;
}
function add(){

        s = "<?php {$c->setAdd();} ?>";
        document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML = s;
}
```

Tanto por AJAX como dessa forma aí de cima, não está alterando o valor do SALDO. Se eu pressionar o botão de SALDO ele me mostra o valor inicial. Se eu pressiono o botão de ADD ele executa a função, porém se eu clicar no botão do SALDO ele continua na mesma.

OBS: No programa original eu criei 4 arquivos: INDEX.PHP, SALDO.PHP, ADD.PHP e CLASS.PHP, para separar o código. E o objetivo não é utilizar métodos GET ou POST e sim atualizar sem carregar a página, como o AJAX faz...

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão de executar funções de uma classe com PHP O.O resolvendo esse problema que eu citei?
Obrigado.

Comment: Do jeito que está não vai dar certo. Poste o código de como você tentou via ajax;

Comment: Atualizado amigão, dê uma olhada novamente por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa conversa entre javascript e PHP, só pode ser feita com ajax, ou no inicio da página com o PHP acima do javascript, para ficar melhor vou adicionar mais 2 inputs

```
    <button class="getSaldo">Saldo</button>

    <input type="text" id="saldo">

    <button class="setSaldo">Add</button>

    <input type="text" id="add">
```

Usei J-query para ficar mais fácil

```
    $(".getSaldo").on("click", function(){


        $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "tuaClasse.php",
                    data: {metodo: 'getSaldo'},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success :  function(response){

                        if (response.codigo == 1) {
                            alert(response.mensagem)
                        }
                        if (response.codigo == 0) {

                            $("#saldo").val(response.valor);

                        }

                    }

                })

    })

    $(".setSaldo").on("click", function(){

        var saldo = $("#add").val();

        $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "tuaClasse.php",
                    data: {metodo: 'setAdd', valor: saldo},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success :  function(response){

                        if (response.codigo == 1) {
                            alert(response.mensagem)
                        }
                        if (response.codigo == 0) {

                            $("#add").val(response.valor);

                        }

                    }

                })

    })
```

No PHP você recebe os métodos pelo POST, existem bibliotecas que agilizam esse processo, na mão fica assim

```
    Class Conta{

      public $saldo;

      public function __construct(){

        $this->saldo = 50;
      }
      public function getSaldo(){

        return $this->saldo;
      }
      public function setAdd(){

        $this->saldo = $this->saldo - 10;
      }
    }

    $c = new Conta();

    $metodo = (isset($_POST['metodo'])) ? $_POST['metodo'] : '';
    $saldo = (isset($_POST['valor'])) ? $_POST['valor'] : '';

    if($metodo == "getSaldo"){

        $valor = $c->getSaldo();

        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0,'valor' => $valor);

        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();

    }

    if($metodo == "setSaldo"){

        $valor = $c->setAdd($saldo); //por causa do método contrutor isso não ira funcionar, mas ele iria adicionar -10 a um valor que você enviasse

        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0,'valor' => $saldo);

        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();

    }

    else{
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 1,'mensagem' => "Erro desconhecido");

        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    }
```

OBS: não testei o código mas é basicamente isso

Comment: Entendi Felipe, vou dá uma estudada no seu código e testar. Você conseguiria fazer esse mesmo código usando AJAX "puro", sem o JQuery? Outra coisa que não entendo é, quando eu estava fazendo como no primeiro exemplo que eu postei, chamando os métodos normalmente, tudo funcionou de boas e quando eu apenas tentei chamar os mesmos por botão foi preciso acrescentar tanto código assim após o objeto ser instanciado?

Comment: Não mecho com javascript puro a tempos kk, então seria difícil... Na verdade é preciso sim, pelo menos se você pretende chama-los sem atualizar a página, orientação a objetos com php é meio complexo com aplicações realTime, outras linguagens de servidor fazem isso melhor, no caso de chamar o método pelo onclick seria inviável, logo o javascript não gera php e também esse tipo de procedimento é muito inseguro

Comment: Entendi rsrsr. Saberia me dizer outro método mais coerente do que o onclick para essa finalidade? Obrigado pelo feedback mano.